# Spark dataframe to a list

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with below schema:

```
root
 |-- cluster_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cluster_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- influencers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- screenName: string (nullable = true)
```

And I need to get unique list of screenName and I am doing it using below code. But collect is a very heavy operation, is there a better way to do it.

```scala
var namesDF = df.select(concat_ws(",", $"cluster_info.influencers.screenName").as("screenName"))
val influencerNameList: List[String] = namesDF.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String]).collect().toList.mkString(",").split(",").toList.distinct
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can select nested field `screenName` as `array` and `explode` it and get the `distinct` values as below

```
var namesDF = df.select($"cluster_info.influencers.screenName").as("screenName"))
  .withColumn("screenName", explode($"screenName"))
  .select("screenName.screenName")
  .distinct()
```

You already got the `distinct` `screenName` 
To get the list you can use

```
namesDF.rdd.map(_.getString(0).collect()
```

But I don't suggest you to collect the result if you have big dataset

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. But when I apply map function on it, it give    Error:Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
        namesDF.map( influencerName => {
Error:not enough arguments for method map

Comment: still same. Might be I am doing something wrong in map.

Comment: I am trying to avoid collect.

Comment: collect fails with: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset